# In Excel, Sum Amount based off occurrences and criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a section in a report that subtotals values based off of criteria. The problem that I'm running into is that I need to only subtotal up to the first 75 occurrences of the criteria. After the first 75 occurrences of the city, I need to do an additional subtotal up to the next 75 occurrences.

For example, work was performed in the city of Dallas for 115 times with a $ value on each row for the 115 occurrences of Dallas. I want to subtotal the $ value for the first 75 occurrences and then subtotal the $ value for the occurrences of 76-115.

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshots about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this Formula:**

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*75,0,75,1))
```

**How it works:**

- Write above written Formula in appropriate cell & fill Down.
- Formula will return Sum of Row 1-75, 76-115 (Sum every 75 Cells).
- In the Formula 75 are editable you may set them as you need.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*